# Circular dependency between modules in nestjs

Tags: node.js, module, nestjs, circular-dependency

The official doc is not clear about how modules in nestjs work and I'm having a problem with a circular dependency. It seems like my module structure is messed up I would like to understand what is wrong with it. The error I'm getting reads:

> Nest cannot create the module instance. Often, this is because of a
> circular dependency between modules. Use forwardRef() to avoid it.
> (Read more: https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/circular-dependency)
> Scope [**AppModule** -> **UsersModule** -> **CategoriesModule**]

Here are the import parts of all the modules mentioned in the error message.

**AppModule:**

```
UsersModule,
SmsRegistrationModule,
AuthModule,
SubscriptionModule,
EmailModule,
EntriesModule,
CategoriesModule,
AwsModule,
SharedModule
```

**UsersModule:**

```
CategoriesModule
```

**CategoriesModule:**

```
AwsModule,
SharedModule,
```

The error raised when I added `SharedModule` to the `CategoriesModule` module. Seems like I'm missing something on how these modules communicate and thus can't resolve this error.

Your help would be much apprecicted.

EDIT:

**SharedModule:**

```
@Module({
  providers: [
    CacheService,
    CodeGenService,
    IsUniqueEmail,
    BasicFileService,
  ],
  imports: [
    CacheModule.registerAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useClass: CacheConfigService,
    }),
    UsersModule,
    AwsModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    CacheService,
    CodeGenService,
    IsUniqueEmail,
    BasicFileService,
  ],
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

Comment: There isn't enough here to know why you might have a circular dependency. What does `SharedModule` have in terms of import modules?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel I've just added info on `SharedModule`, please, have a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `SharedModule` imports `UserModule`, so the import chain (or at least the one I'm going to follow here) is `AppModule -> UsersModule -> CategoriesModule -> SharedModule -> UsersModule -> CategoriesMOdule -> SharedModule -> ...`. To get around this, either the `SharedModule` should not import the `UsersModule`, or you should forward reference the `CategoriesModule` from the `UserModule`, the `UserModule` from the `SharedModule` and the `SharedModule` from the `CategoriesModule`. This is my first time seeing a circular dependency a few modules deep, so I can't give the exact syntax of how to work with the `forwardRef` method.

Comment: Well seems like I'll look into it more closely a tad later to figure out what led to this mess, for now I've found the way to exclude `UserModule` from `SharedModule` and it worked, thank you a lot for helping me!